# HelloWorld Jersey REST web service on Tomcat using -security mode

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I followed a basic HelloWorld [tutorial](https://medium.com/@madhawacperera/simple-java-restful-web-service-with-jersey-jax-rs-implementation-615739857961) to get an example REST web service going under Tomcat using Jersey. Everything runs absolutely fine, and I get the output I expect.

However, my Tomcat host insists that we test our apps locally using the `-security` mode. When I do this, the app no longer works. I had to battle with a few permission related issues first, but they seem to be resolved now, and this is the final error. It takes me to an Error 500 page, and this is the top of the stacktrace:

```
22-Mar-2020 17:33:42.842 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  rc.framedata
22-Mar-2020 17:33:42.845 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found:
  class rc.framedata.HelloService
22-Mar-2020 17:33:42.845 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init No provider classes found.
22-Mar-2020 17:33:42.848 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
22-Mar-2020 17:33:43.094 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write A message body writer for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter

22-Mar-2020 17:33:43.095 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.logException Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
        javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

                at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:284)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
                at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
                at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
                at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
                at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:549)
                at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)                at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:170)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:225)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
                at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:549)
                at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)                at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:609)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

                ... 58 more
```

It runs fine without `-security` so I'm fairly sure my `pom.xml` dependencies etc must be set up correctly, but they look like this:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.53</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

My `web.xml` looks like this:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>rc.framedata</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And finally, my `HelloService.java` class looks like this:

```
package rc.framedata;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloService {

    @GET
    @Path("{clientName}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response greetClient(@PathParam("clientName") String name){
        String output = "Hi " + name;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

}
```

I'm at a loss as to how to debug this or figure out what could be wrong. If I Google the error, I only find people who can't get their project working full-stop, but I can.... it just doesn't work with `-security` mode.

I'm a complete novice with Tomcat and Jersey so any help is greatly appreciated in advance.
(using Java 1.8.0_231 and Tomcat 8.5.51 on Windows 10)

Comment: Could you update your question to show the full stack trace if possible, or is there some reason you truncated the output?

Comment: @skomisa Done. No reason, I was just trying to be succinct.